# Replacement for chrome.Port prototype

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

My extension, [sharkzapper](https://github.com/adammw/sharkzapper) was working in older versions of Google Chrome but stopped some time when Chrome 18 or 19 was released, due to my use of the chrome.Port.prototype property which no longer exists. I was previously using it to create an object which extended a chrome.Port via prototypical inheritance so I could log all messages in and out for debugging. The source code in particular of this portion is [here](https://github.com/adammw/sharkzapper/blob/master/lib/sharkzapper_background.js#L48-63).

Is there any other way to inherit from chrome.Port, or any other workaround I could use to get my extension working again?

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with this? Not sure how [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jjhlhcmfkkhnikmehakaceciakbppoij) extension is doing it but they seem to be providing similar functionality as yours.

Comment: Yes, I know how the other extension works, it uses Chrome's request API rather than ports, and explicitly polls for the status of the player via DOM every second, whereas my extension uses a more asynchronous technique of hooking into internal callbacks and pushing changes to the front-end. Although they end up performing a similar function, they are designed in two very different ways, and as such does not solve the problem the question is asking. Strictly speaking, extending the Port is not really needed as it used only for debugging, but I'd like to find a proper solution.